# How are function parameters stored in lisp?

Tags: function, parameters, lisp, common-lisp

I assumed that values passed into a lisp function are assigned to a quote matching the name of the parameter. However, I was surprised that this:

```
(defun test (x) (print (eval 'x)))
(test 5)
```

doesn't work (the variable x is unbound). So if parameters aren't stored as symbols in the function, what exactly IS x in this example? Is there a way to access parameters from a symbol matching the parameter name?

More context:
What I would like to do is something like this:

```
defun slice (r1 c1 r2 c2 board)
  (dolist (param '(r1 c1 r2 c2))  ;adjust for negative indices
    (if (< (eval param) 0)
      (set param (+ (length board) (eval param)))))
        ;Body of function
```

Basically, I want to iterate through the first four parameters and make an adjustment to any of their values if they are < 0. Of course, I could do a let and have an individual line for each parameter, but considering I'm doing the same thing for each of the four parameters this seemed cleaner.
However, I get the error that the variable R1 is unbound.

Comment: It is implementation specific. [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html) give some information in the Foreign Function Interface chapter, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to access parameters from a symbol matching the parameter name?

Not for lexical binding. Common Lisp gives no way to access a lexical variable from a similar named symbol. You would need to declare the variable *special*.

> So if parameters aren't stored as symbols in the function, what exactly IS x in this example?

A processor register? A part of a stack frame?

With dynamic binding:

```
CL-USER 40 > (defun foo (a b)
               (declare (special a b))
               (dolist (v '(a b))
                 (if (zerop (symbol-value v))
                     (set v 10)))
               (values a b))
FOO

CL-USER 41 > (foo 1 0)
1
10
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to use the same code with just one extra line to declare the parameters as special

Comment: @murphyslaw Do be sure that you understand the other possible consequences of declaring a variable special.  The variable will be bound with dynamic scope which means, e.g., that `(let ((x 3)) (declare (special x)) (funcall (let ((x 4)) (declare (special x)) (lambda () x))))` will return `3`, not `4`, even though when the `lambda` function is created `x` is bound to `4`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - Thanks for the heads up, I clearly need do do some more reading on this. Just to be sure, declaring a parameter as special will not have any implications for that symbol outside of the function block, correct?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what exactly you mean by outside, but take a look at [these examples](http://pastebin.com/ApY9zNmV).

Answer (score 5):

That's basically how lexical binding works: the variable name gets replaced within the lexical scope with a direct reference to where the variable's value is stored. Binding the variable name's `symbol-value` is only done for dynamic variable which you can declare with `special`.

One way to avoid repeating yourself would be a macro:

```
(defmacro with-adjusting ((&rest vars) adjust-value &body body)
  `(let ,(loop for var in vars
               collect `(,var (if (minusp ,var)
                                (+ ,var ,adjust-value)
                                ,var)))
     ,@body))

(defun slice (r1 c1 r2 c2 board)
  (with-adjusting (r1 c1 r2 c2) (length board)
    ;; function body
```

Comment: That's a good answer. A macro is quite useful here. Small drawback: the compiled code gets larger.

Answer (score 2):

As Rainer explained, you cannot access the lexical argument value by its name.

What you can do instead is use the [`&rest`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dac.htm) argument together with [`destructuring-bind`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm) if you want the variables too:

```
(defun slice (board &rest params)
  (destructuring-bind (r1 c1 r2 c2)
      (mapcar (lambda (param) ;adjust for negative indices
                (if (minusp param)
                    (+ (length board) param)
                    param))
              params)
    ... operate on r1 c1 r2 c2 ...))
```